# Send email only to newly added panel members

Tags: qualtrics

I have a survey created for University course enrollments and the link to the survey is individualized with embedded data from a panel. Each morning I would like to send out the survey through Qualtrics to everyone who signed up the prior day. I am using the Qualtrics REST API to build the panel and send the email.

With the REST API version 2.4 I can successfully add members to a panel. I can successfully send an email to panel members. What I cannot figure out is how to send the email only to newly added panel members (the ones that I add because the enrolled the prior day). I only want newly added panel members to get this email.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `getPanel` has an option called `LastRecipientID` that will filter the results how you want. Make sure you keep track of the last recipient ID when you call the API each day and pass it back in the next day. That will return all the users that have been added since the last time you called the API.

Official Documentation:

**LastRecipientID**: The last Recipient ID from a previous API call. Start returning everyone AFTER this Recipient

[Source](https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php#getPanel_2.4)